# iPhone Objective-C memory leak issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, memory-leaks

Im having a bit of an issue where i create an array of button objects and place them onto a view, something like

```
for(int i=0;i<_number;i++) { 
    _object = [[object alloc]init];
    [self.view addsubview:_object];
}
```

However if i release them straight after i add them to the view, they break when the user taps on them naturally. My question is where would be the best place to release them?

The list is repopulated periodically so currently im keeping a reference to the objects and when i got to repopulate i release them there by iterating through the view like

```
for(_object *obj in self.view) { 
    [obj removeFromSuperview]; 
    [obj release]; 
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Typo in the code at line 1? You alloc and init `_object`, but add `object` to the view.

Comment: And btw, you should be able to release them right after you've added them to the view. If it breaks, there's something else going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The superview retains its subviews, so there is no need for you to retain them. Especially since you don't have references to the objects themselves (i.e. you are taking references from self.view) you shouldn't bother with the memory management of them.

There seem to be a few typos here so I assume you're not posting real code. (object vs _object)

The first for loop could look like:

```
for(int i=0;i<_number;i++) {
    _object = [[[Object alloc]init] autorelease];
    [self.view addsubview:_object];
}
```

The second one:

```
for( Object *obj in self.view.subviews ) {
    [obj removeFromSuperview];
}
```

(changed `object` to `Object` for clarity)

Comment: Yeah i missed that typo, i was just hacking out a quick example since the actual code is a fair bit longer. Thank you for the fast response though, my code is probably breaking elsewhere.